# Динамический путь для upload_to в модели django (models.FileField)

Tags: python, fileupload, django

Здравствуйте, 
В django до версии 1.4 была возможность в модели для models.FileField указать "динамически" создаваемый путь хранения файлов в переменную upload_to

```
models.py
#...
attach        = models.FileField(verbose_name=u'Приложение', blank=True, upload_to=lambda instance, filename: 'attach/%s/%s' % (instance.id,filename))
```

D django версии 1.4 похоже id присваивается позже и поэтому instance.id = None и так же instance.pk = None. Подскажите как можно указать в путь именно id модели.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваш вопрос немного ставит в тупик, потому как лично у меня в версии до 1.4 также `id` не был доступен в `upload_to`.

Вообще вопрос хранения путей файлов достаточно избит. По мне, так самый нормальный вариант с построением хеша от `timestamp` + имя файла и создание директорий по первым 4м символам хеша

```
upload_to = 'upload_path/%s/%s/%s.jpg' % (hash[:1], hash[2:3], hash)
```

**UPDATE**
Касательно именно id в имени файла. Вам надо после сохранения файла, т.е. после присвоения `id` в базе генерировать новый путь и соответственно перемещать файл по новому пути. На мое субъективное мнение уж слишком затратная операция получается.

**UPDATE2**

```
import uuid
def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
    return 'uploads/%s/%s/%s.jpg' % (filename[:1], filename[2:3], filename)
```

и в модели

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path,
                        null=True,
                        blank=True,
                        verbose_name=_(u'Contact list'))
```

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду так?

 attach        = models.FileField(verbose_name=u'Приложение', blank=True, upload_to='attach/%Y/%m/%d')

Comment: я имею в виду то, что `upload_to` принимает `callable` объект, т.е. это может быть функция. Пример смотрите в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [документации для версий до 1.4 **включительно**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

> In most cases, this object will not
> have been saved to the database yet,
> so if it uses the default AutoField,
> it might not yet have a value for its
> primary key field

Соответсвенно, такое поведение было и раньше, возможно вы ошиблись.

Да, можно сделать грязный хак для решения этой проблемы с отлавливанием сигнала сохранения модели и перемещения файла по новому пути... надо ли оно вам - это должны решить сами.

---

Либо, раз уж в документации говорится именно об `AutoField`, [попробуйте заменить поле `id`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) у модели на что-то свое (хэш от файла? UUID? Сами решайте). Возможно, этот трюк сработает.

Comment: Согласен, я ошибся, только что проверил предыдущий проект в котором сохраняется id потому, что элемент был создан ранее, а файл записан позже.

Comment: Решил вопрос, сделал так:

attach        = models.FileField(verbose_name=u'Приложение', blank=True, upload_to=lambda instance, filename: 'attach/%(id)s/%(dt)s/%(filename)s' % {'id': instance.author.id, 'filename': filename, 'dt': datetime.date.today()})

Answer (score 1):

ID будет только после вставки ряда, а ряд вставится только после записи всех полей. Поэтому нельзя знать ID пока объект не сохранен. Самое простое — в транзакции сначала сохранить с `attach=None`, потом обновить поле и пересохранить. Как-то в таком духе:

```
with transaction.commit_on_success():
    file = File(..., attach=None)
    file.save()
    file.attach = attachment
    file.save()
```

В рамках оптимизации можно сделать предвыборку ID, но это не очень красиво и vendor-specific решение, которое сложно переносить между базами данных. Зато избавляет от пары INSERT+UPDATE, ограничиваясь одной вставкой. Для PostgreSQL, который умеет SEQUENCEs, например будет что-то в духе:

```
from django.db import connection
assert connection.vendor == "postgresql"
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT nextval('seq_files_id')")
new_id, = cursor.fetchone()
file = File(id=new_id, ...)
file.save()
```